# Do we see Mikiya Kokutou after the time leap at the end of Kara no Kyoukai: Mirai Fukuin?

Tags: the-garden-of-sinners

During the scene in which Mitsuru was going to be hired by the gang of Mikiya and Shiki, we see a man with black glasses sitting in front of Mitsuru (see picture below). Is it Mikiya or just a member of the gang?

I mean, on the one hand, when Mitsuru was referring to Mikiya (the current gang leader), we were able to see this man. Hence we could conclude that it's Mikiya. But on the other hand, it wouldn't be surprising if the producers simply showed a gang member who's in charge of recruiting.

I'm still a bit doubtful that this man might be Mikiya since his personality seems a bit contradictory to his younger self. Though, it also needs to be considered that there was a time leap of over 10 years.

So, is this man Mikiya or just a gang member?

[image]

Comment: I thought it was a lieutenant of the Ryougi family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guy's simply the loan shark that Mitsuru was dealing with. He also stands up at attention when Ryougi, the family head, walks in, like an underling would do.

Answer (score 1):

although this a question from 3 years ago but i just finished watching entire Kara no Kyoukai Series. i just conclude that the guy in front of mitsuru that appears as a 'loan sharks' is actually Shiki's Bodyguard.